# Load data into threads of Java ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am writing server to response to the queries of the same type. As I will have several clients I want to perform tasks in parallel. Prior to performing task I need to load static data from file - this process takes most of the time. When this is done I can answer any amount of queries using this loaded data.

I want to use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)` as my `ExecutorService`, so it manages all multithreading staff for me. If I understand correctly threads are created once and then all my task are run using this threads. So it will ideally fit my problem, if it is possible to load data into every thread when it is created and use it for all tasks which will be run using this thread.

Is this possible?

Another idea is just to create array of several copies of the same data with boolean `isInUse`. As there will be fixed amount of tasks performed in parallel, just select the one data entity that is free at the moment, mark it taken and mark it free in the end of performing the task.
But I think I will need somehow synchronise this boolean parameter between threads.

(I need several copies of data as it can be modified while performing task, but will be returned to initial state after task is performed.)

Comment: If this data is big or it takes time to load, I would recommend you to use thread-safe data structure like ConcurrentHashMap and share the same reference across. However it will be tricky to keep this data safe.

Otherwise, you could use several techniques, in every task load data again, or even better use a thread local variable

Comment: Re, "possible to load data into every thread...?" A thread doesn't have any "inside" into which you can load data. All of the threads in a program see the same global address space. If you read the file into a global, effectively-immutable data structure before you start the thread, then all of the threads will be able to use it.

Comment: If you have a single, large file of data, I would use one thread to read the entirety of it, do whatever processing / transformation is needed, and put the data into some data structure where threads can later access it. Using multiple threads to concurrently read the same file from the one logical device (hard drive) does not seem worth the effort – the code will take more time to write because it will be more complicated (which also means more chance for bugs) and in the end you'll still be limited by the underlying drive's I/O performance.

Comment: I think I have badly formulated the question. The data is map of the game. But algorithm can modify it, and will return data to initial state after finishing the task. I want to have 10 instances of the same data loaded into the memory and 10 threads which will pick task from queue and use it’s copy of loaded data to produce the response. So thread number 1 use data number 1 and etc. But then thread picks up next task it use still the same data, doesn’t load one more time.

Comment: Seems like you want a pool of your game map objects. Just load it with N objects, and each task will take an object from pool, and return to the pool after job is done. You can use ConcurrentLinkedQueue for this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.